# Python CSV get particular row data

Tags: python, csv

This is csv file

```
name,country,code
Georgina,Saint Helena,ET
Brooks,Austria,LR
Rosaline,Peru,DZ
```

How to get a particular row data without looping the whole csv file?

Looking for following syntax:
If searchName  exist in csv, extract the data

```
searchName = 'Brooks'
with open('name.csv', 'r') as file:
  reader = csv.DictReader(file)
  for row in reader:
    if (row['name']) == searchName :
      print(row['name'] + ' >> ' + row['country'])
```

### Thanks

Update panda solution for those who  interested

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
select_row = df.loc[df['name'] == 'Brooks']
if select_row.empty:
    print('No records')
else:
    print('Print Record')
    print(select_row.country)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what `A` is in `if(row['name'] == A:` ?

Comment: should be if (row['name']) == searchName:

Comment: why don't you use pandas?

Comment: Are you looking only for the first match of your searchName? Or all matches?

Comment: By design, the actual csv have unique names. The first match should be OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get first instance

```
search_name = 'Brooks'
with open('name.csv', 'r') as file: 
    output = re.search(f'{search_name}.*', file.read())

row = output.group().split(',')
print(row[0], '>>' ,row[1])
```

Get all instances

```
search_name = 'Brooks'
with open('name.csv', 'r') as file: 
    output = re.findall(f'{search_name}.*', file.read())

for row in output: 
    items = row.split(',')
    print(items[0], '>>' ,items[1])
```

Using DataFrames

```
import pandas as pd 

search_name = 'Brooks'
df = pd.read_csv('name.csv')
output = df[df.name == search_name].iloc[0]
print(output['name'], '>>', output['country'])
```

Comment: Thanks for alternative solution.  use of column name ( row['name'] ) is preferred because column numbers might change from time to time.  Will study on how to use panda

Comment: I posted a pandas example at the bottom. This will retrieve the first matching instance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using pandas and make your life easier, try something like this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('name.csv')

if df.iloc[5, 6]:
# execute condition
else
# execute another condition
```

I have given you an outline,you can try to use this and come up with a solution for your issue.

Comment: I think you want a python script other than using pandas DataFrame and get the value of a single row without iterating the rows. I don't think so to get the value without looping each row.

Comment: panda solution for those who  interested

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
select_row = df.loc[df['name'] == 'Brooks']
if select_row.empty:
    print('No records')
else:
    print('Print Record')
    print(select_row.country)

Answer (score 1):

Although dataframe seems to be the best option, if you treat the csv as a simple text file, This should help you:

```
searchName = 'Brooks'
with open('name.csv', 'r') as f:
    foo = f.read()

items=re.findall(f"{searchName}.*$",foo,re.MULTILINE)

print(items)
```

Output:

`['Brooks,Austria,LR']`